# MongoDB aggregation within the same collection

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, sorting, nosql

I'm new to mongodb quarrying stuff. I have this mongo collection for messages. This collection developed for chat app. "**members**" array first element represent the sender ID and the second element represent the receiver ID.

**Sender** : 631012d34a181605afe342c1 
**Receiver**: 62e8845c3e1d191dfdc1a244

```
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "63f992e729c2692f5ccfb23d",
        "members": [
            "631012d34a181605afe342c1",
            "62e8845c3e1d191dfdc1a244"
        ],
        "message": [
            {
                "from": "631012d34a181605afe342c1",
                "body": "Hi",
                "time": "2023-02-24T10:08:43.070Z",
                "_id": "63f992e729c2692f5ccfb23e"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

what I want to achieve is to filter if the message sender already have previous messages with a particular receiver. if not I will create a new document for the messages.

What I tried so far is the bellow aggregation query but it gives empty result.

```
{
    $match: {members: {$in: [new Types.ObjectId(sender)]}}
},
{
   $lookup: {
     from: "messages",
     let: {"receivern": receiver},
     pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$members", "$$receivern"] }}}],
     as: "names"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Lookup should be modified as below.

```
$lookup: {
    from: "messages",
    let: {"receivern": new Types.ObjectId(receiver)},
    pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$receivern", "$members"] }}}],
    as: "names"
}
```

This query search within the same document and inside of my members array.